# Entity Framework BulkInsert not inserting child entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I have 2 tables `INS_Staging_UMLERTransaction(Parent)` and `INS_Staging_UMLERBlueCard(Child)`.

I need to insert 1000 records, when I use bulk insert it is inserting only parent table. The following is my code.

```
 _indnCon.BulkInsert(_DataToTrans);                                       
 _indnCon.BulkInsert(_DataToTrans.SelectMany(m => 
                      m.INS_Staging_UMLERBlueCard));
 _indnCon.BulkSaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **BulkInsert** or **BulkSaveChanges** method in Entity Framework Extended.

So in my answer, I will assume you are using [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) library.

---

Since the v3.12.6 ([Release Note](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/releases/tag/v3.12.6)), a **IncludeGraph** option has been added to include child entities.

#### Example

```
_indnCon.BulkInsert(_DataToTrans, operation => operation.IncludeGraph = true);
```

*Note: You don't have to call BulkSaveChanges after calling BulkInsert. Bulk Operation is performed directly in the database.*

**Answer Sub-Question:**

> I'm getting an exception when I use IncludeGraph. The exception is "A
>   default DbContext context must exist, or a context factory must be
>   provided (EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory). This setting is
>   required for some features like IncludeGraph."

This error mean you don’t have a default constructor for your context. A way to build a new context is required for this feature.

Here is an example how to specify a context factory when no default constructors exists:

```
EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = context => new CurrentContext(My.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception when I use IncludeGraph. The exception is "A default DbContext context must exist, or a context factory must be provided (EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory). 
This setting is required for some features like IncludeGraph.".

Comment: There is one more exception, "There is already a generated proxy type for the object layer type 'PRIM.InsightNucleus.Data.INS_Staging_UMLERTransaction'. 
This occurs when the same object layer type is mapped by two or more different models in an AppDomain."

Comment: Here I'm using this class in 2 DBContext

Comment: This is why there is a "context" variable. By using typeof(context), you can easily find our from which is the right context to initialize

Answer (score -2):

This is how I have solved. Postgres database has been used.

```
services.AddDbContextPool<postgresContext>(options =>
 {                
     options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConString"));
 });
```

// Added this line when such errors were coming

```
EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = context =>
 {
         var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<postgresContext>();                
         optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString
("PostgresConString"));
                return new postgresContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
};
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? I think you intended to answer another question.