# A default DbContext context must exist, or a context factory must be provided

Tags: entity-framework

I'm getting the following error while performing "Bulk Insert" using EntityFramework extensions.

```
_indnCon.BulkInsert(_DataToTrans, operation => operation.IncludeGraph = true);
```

Exception occurs in the above line and here is the exception.

> A default DbContext context must exist, 
>       or a context factory must be provided (EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory). 
>       This setting is required for some features like IncludeGraph.

Here I'm passing the Connection String to the DBContext manually.

```
using (InsightDataContext _indnCon = new InsightDataContext(_connectionString))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you already declaring _indnCon as a global variable?

Comment: no, writing my code within that declaration

Comment: Do you have an InsightDataContext open more than once?  Such as opening it in a method then calling another method which opens it again? Edit: Are you extending IDisposable on your class?

Comment: using (InsightDataContext _indnCon = new InsightDataContext(_connectionString))
                                { _indnCon.BulkInsert(_UmlerResponse, m => m.IncludeGraph = true);}

Comment: this is my code

Comment: Do you have an InsightDataContext open more than once? Such as opening it in a method then calling another method which opens it again? -
( No)  Edit: Are you extending IDisposable on your class? - (No)

Comment: Are you successfully opening your and using your dbcontext anywhere else or is it just ``BulkInsert`` causing this issue?

Comment: only for BulkInsert & all are working fine except that, that too when I include operation => operation.IncludeGraph = true in that line

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `IncludeGraph` feature needs to be able to create a new instance of your context, even if you already instantiated the context yourself in this scope. So, as the message says, you can try setting a default constructor for your context:

```
EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = context => new CurrentContext(yourConnectionString);
```

The info comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898323/entity-framework-bulkinsert-not-inserting-child-entities).